# Best jQuery TextEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, rich-text-editor, forms, http-post

Anyone know of a good Rich Text Editor preferably in jQuery, that has a good interface, is customize-able and easy to integrate in forms where submitting data is crutial?

I am making a website where people would need to send formatted texts..

I tried TinyMCE and i found it too much for what i wanted, then tried NicEdit, found some bugs in it, corrected some but it is a pain to get the typed HTML when i need to submit the form so i am looking for any alternative you might want to offer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/). You can configure exactly which buttons you expose to your users, and it's possible even to have different configuration for differents users. I'm using it and have not found any important bug.

Comment: Looks really nice ;)
Is it easy to get the content HTML too? (I hope so :D)

Comment: awesome, im gonna give it a shot then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple but rich enough http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/

Comment: i have used this, but it doesn't seem to have a color picker which i need for sure